# What windows OS version do you get when you do a full factory reset?

Tags: windows, windows-8, operating-systems

I got my laptop with windows 8 I believe. Since then, I've upgraded to windows 10 and now recently windows 11. If I do a full recovery (factory reset) and choose to not keep any personal files, I am wondering which OS version does it go back to? I want to confirm it will be 11 before I try. Does anyone know?

[image]

Comment: If you use the OEM factory partition, it will be Windows 8.1, if you use the method within Windows it will be Windows 11.

Comment: @Ramhound I added a picture. Is this the windows method that will keep it windows 11 after resetting?

Comment: Thats the Windows method.